# Adding legends in Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have generated a plot with multiple line using a for loop. But I cannot add a legend to this graph.
Below is the code I have tried.

```
for l in range(3,8,1):
     seq=np.arange(0,20)
     X=stats.poisson(l)
     seq_pmf = X.pmf(seq)
     plt.plot(seq, seq_pmf,label=l)
```

I want the legend labels as λ=3, λ=4...like wise

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `plt.legend()` before showing the graph.

e.g:

```
for l in range(3,8,1):
     seq=np.arange(0,20)
     X=stats.poisson(l)
     seq_pmf = X.pmf(seq)
     plt.plot(seq, seq_pmf,label=l)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes. But how can I get it as, λ=3, λ=4...like wise. Instead of just the λ value?

Comment: In the `label` argument you can specify `label="$\lambda$=l"`.

Comment: Oh, right. You can use f-string: `label=f'$\lambda$ = {l}'`

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
for l in range(3,8,1):
    seq=np.arange(0,20)
    X=stats.poisson(l)
    seq_pmf = X.pmf(seq)
    plt.plot(seq, seq_pmf,label=r'$\lambda$ = '+str(l))
    plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: plt.plot(seq, seq_pmf,label="λ={0}".format(l))        This works!

Comment: right. it almost the same. The difference only is how you create this final label string: explicitly use greek lambda-symbol or it code